# change xaml control's value in multiple pages from a separate cs/namespace

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform, signalr.client, visual-studio-2017

first of all I'm sorry for my poor explanation as I am fairly new in c# and mobile app development.
I have to pages in my Xamarin cross platform project for IOS and Android. Lets say a.xaml and b.xaml. Both the pages have two different namespace (for example first and second). Lets say I have a label (lblA) in a.xaml and a button in b.xaml (btnB). What I want to do is to update lblA.text when btnB is clicked. I tried x:Name="btnB" but can not access btnB from Second namespace. Is there a way to do that?

Context: Now let me explain the background of my problem. I am trying to implement SignalR in my multipage cross platform project. Where I have a separate signalr class and on message received event I want to update relevant label/grid in different pages. Therefore, I need to access controls in all my pages. When I try to execute Debug.Writeline("received message from signalr") it works perfectly fine but when I try to change First.lblA.text it doesnt work neither it throws any exceptions.

Therefore, any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

SignalR.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SigClient
{

    public class Client
    {
        public string _user = "";
        public string _prefix = "";
        public string _url = "";
        public int _port = 80;

        public string User
        {
            get
            {
                return _user;
            }
            set
            {
                _user = value;
            }
        }
        public string Prefix
        {
            get
            {
                return _prefix;
            }
            set
            {
                _prefix = value;
            }
        }
        public string HubUrl
        {
            get
            {
                return _url;
            }
            set
            {
                _url = value;
            }
        }
        public int Port
        {
            get
            {
                return _port;
            }
            set
            {
                _port = value;
            }
        }


        private HubConnection _connection;
        private IHubProxy _proxy;


        public void Clients()
        {
            var querystringData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            querystringData.Add("userName", "{\"userName\":\"" + _prefix + "_" + "driver" + _user + "\"}");
            _connection = new HubConnection(_url + ":" + _port.ToString(), querystringData);
            _proxy = _connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
        }

        private App1.MainPage page;
        public Label lbl;
        public async Task Connect()
        {
            try
            {
                page = new App1.MainPage();
                _proxy.On<string, string>("addNewMessageToPage", (name, msg) =>
                //-> I want to update testlbl.text=msg
                //page.exLbl.Text = msg //doesnt do anything
                //Debug.WriteLine(msg) //This line works fine
                deb("", msg)

                );
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }


            await _connection.Start();
        }

        public async Task deb(string msg, string msg1)
        {
            //page.exLbl.Text = msg1
            page.DoStuff(msg1);
            lbl = page.exLbl;
            lbl.Text = msg1;
            Debug.WriteLine(msg + "-" + msg1);
        }
        public Task Send(string message)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("SignalR message sent");
            return _proxy.Invoke("SendToOperators", "eb5_operator123456", "NewJobSaved", "system");
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage"
             x:FieldModifier="public">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" 
               VerticalOptions="Center" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center" ></Label>
        <Label x:Name="testLbl" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" x:FieldModifier="public"></Label>
        <Button x:Name="testBtn" Text="Connect"></Button>
        <Button x:Name="testSend" Text="Send Msg"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using SigClient;
using UIKit;


namespace App1
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public Label exLbl
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public Client cclient=new Client();
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            testLbl.Text = "I'm Loaded...";

            cclient.User = "111";
            cclient.Prefix = "xxx";
            cclient.HubUrl = "http://255.255.255.255";
            cclient.Port = 80;

            testBtn.Clicked += new EventHandler(testBtn_Click);
            testSend.Clicked += new EventHandler(testSend_Click);
        }

        async void testSend_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                await cclient.Send("test");
                testLbl.Text = "Sent!!!";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                testLbl.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
        async void testBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                cclient.Clients();
                await cclient.Connect();
                testLbl.Text = "Connected!!!";
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                testLbl.Text = ex.Message;

            }
        }
        public void DoStuff(string x)
        {
            this.testLbl.Text=x;  //this line doesnt response
            Debug.WriteLine(x+"dostuff"); //this line works fine
        }
    }
}
```

Again, I beg your pardon for my novice coding style. Please feel free to ask me any questions.

Thanks

Comment: You can only have 1 page visible at the time and you shouldn't be updating pages which are not currently visible since you don't know the state of these, saying this what you are trying to do doesn't seem like a good approach. Why don't you expose public events from the SignalR client which can be later consumed from your app pages and there you update the state? Or you can even use the MessagingCenter.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your suggestion. Just read a few articles about it and it looks promising. I will be off for next few days and when i come back will give it a shot. Hope it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default controls in .Net are protected so they can be accessed publicly. You can always expose the control publicly.

For example, in class A you can define a readonly property that returns the protected control.

```
public class A {
    public Label LblA { get {return lblA;}}
}
```

The in B you can access LblA because it is now public.

```
public class B {
    private A aRef; /*a reference to an actual instance of A*/
    public void setALabel() {
        aRef.LblA.text="Some Text";
    }
}
```

In your code the client is creating a new instance of the Main Page upon connection. For the code to work the page variable in the client class needs to hold a reference to the page that was already created.

SignalR.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SigClient
{

    public class Client
    {
        public string _user = "";
        public string _prefix = "";
        public string _url = "";
        public int _port = 80;

        public string User
        {
            get
            {
                return _user;
            }
            set
            {
                _user = value;
            }
        }
        public string Prefix
        {
            get
            {
                return _prefix;
            }
            set
            {
                _prefix = value;
            }
        }
        public string HubUrl
        {
            get
            {
                return _url;
            }
            set
            {
                _url = value;
            }
        }
        public int Port
        {
            get
            {
                return _port;
            }
            set
            {
                _port = value;
            }
        }


        private HubConnection _connection;
        private IHubProxy _proxy;


        public void Clients(App1.MainPage page)
        {
            this.page=page;
            var querystringData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            querystringData.Add("userName", "{\"userName\":\"" + _prefix + "_" + "driver" + _user + "\"}");
            _connection = new HubConnection(_url + ":" + _port.ToString(), querystringData);
            _proxy = _connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
        }

        private App1.MainPage page;
        //public Label lbl;
        public async Task Connect()
        {
            try
            {
                _proxy.On<string, string>("addNewMessageToPage", (name, msg) =>

                page.PublicLbl.Text = msg 
                //Debug.WriteLine(msg) //This line works fine
                deb("", msg)

                );
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }


            await _connection.Start();
        }

        public async Task deb(string msg, string msg1)
        {
            //you don't need both of these lines
            page.PublicLbl.Text = msg1
            page.DoStuff(msg1);
            Debug.WriteLine(msg + "-" + msg1);
        }
        public Task Send(string message)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("SignalR message sent");
            return _proxy.Invoke("SendToOperators", "eb5_operator123456", "NewJobSaved", "system");
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage"
             x:FieldModifier="public">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" 
               VerticalOptions="Center" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center" ></Label>
        <Label x:Name="testLbl" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
        <Label x:Name="clientLbl" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
        <Button x:Name="testBtn" Text="Connect"></Button>
        <Button x:Name="testSend" Text="Send Msg"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using SigClient;
using UIKit;


namespace App1
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public Label PublicLbl
        {
            get {return clientLbl;}
        }

        public Client cclient
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cclient=new Client(this);
            testLbl.Text = "I'm Loaded...";

            cclient.User = "111";
            cclient.Prefix = "xxx";
            cclient.HubUrl = "http://255.255.255.255";
            cclient.Port = 80;

            testBtn.Clicked += new EventHandler(testBtn_Click);
            testSend.Clicked += new EventHandler(testSend_Click);
        }

        async void testSend_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                await cclient.Send("test");
                testLbl.Text = "Sent!!!";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                testLbl.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
        async void testBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                cclient.Clients();
                await cclient.Connect();
                //this line will going to overwrite the client message in the original code
                testLbl.Text = "Connected!!!";
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                testLbl.Text = ex.Message;

            }
        }
        public void DoStuff(string x)
        {
            this.clientLbl.Text = x;  
            Debug.WriteLine(x + " dostuff"); //this line works fine
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just now tried but didnt work. Change in MainPage: public Label exLbl { get { return testLbl; } } and in Sinalr.cs : private App1.MainPage page;
        private Label lbl;
        public async Task Connect()
        {
            try
            {
                page = new App1.MainPage();
                _proxy.On<string, string>("addNewMessageToPage", (name, msg) =>
                page.exLbl.Text = msg
                //Debug.WriteLine(msg)
                //deb("", msg)

                );
            }. Thanks for your quick resposne

Comment: page = new App1.MainPage(); is creating a new instance of MainPage. You should be referencing an existing instance the client is already seeing not creating a new one.

Comment: For instance, in your main page constructor add  `cclient.page=this;` and in client change ` private App1.MainPage page;` to `public App1.MainPage page;` or pass the main page as a parameter to the client constructor and set the private variable in the client constructor

Comment: I fully modified your code to show how it should be implemented.

Comment: Superb man. I will check when i go home and will give u heads up. Thanks a lot for your effort mate. Really appreciate.